# How Do I use mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, web, hosting, builder

I have a url with:

> http://example.com/index.php

I want it to be

> /index

I will need to use mod_rewrite to make a virtual folder for a PHP or HTML file with .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index/
```

This is not working

Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want reverse rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php
```

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer was helpfull, you may accept it